# Can I use linq to achieve the same thing this foreach loop does?

Tags: c#, linq

Here's the c# code that I have:

```
private double get806Fees (Loan loan)
{
    Loan.Fee.Items class806;
    foreach (Loan.Fee.Item currentFee in loan.Item.Fees)
    {
        if (currentFee.Classification == 806) class806.Add(currentFee);
    }

    // then down here I will return the sum of all items in class806
}
```

Can I do this using linq?  If so, how?  I have never used linq and i've read in several places that using linq instead of a foreach loop is faster... is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to some existing answers, but doing the projection in the query, to make the `Sum` call a lot simpler:

```
var sum = (from fee in loan.Items.Fees
           where fee.Classification == 806
           select fee.SomeValueToSum).Sum();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
loan.Item.Fees.
    Where(x => x.Classification == 806).
    Sum(x => x.SomeValueProperty)
```

Whether it is faster or not is debatable. IMO, both complexities are the same, the non-LINQ version may be faster.

Comment: While this is true, I personally favor the LINQ version over the non-LINQ because I think it expresses its intent more clearly and in less code.

Answer (score 2):

```
var q =
  from currentFee in loan.Item.Fees
  where currentFee.Classification == 806
  select currentFee;

var sum = q.Sum(currentFee => currentFee.Fee);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private double get806Fees(Loan loan)
{
    return load.Item.Fees.
        Where(f => f.Classification == 806).
        Sum(f => f.ValueToCalculateSum);
}
```

I'm assuming here that `ValueToCalculateSum` is also a double. If it's not then you have to convert it before it is returned.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers so far are assuming that you're summing up `loan.Fees`.  But the code you actually posted calls `Items.Add()` to add each `Item` in `loan.Fees.Items` to an `Items` object, and it's that `Items` object (and not `loan.Fees`, which is also an `Items` object) that you say you want to sum up.

Now, if `Items` is just a simple collection class, then there's no need to do anything other than what people are suggesting here.  But if there's some side-effect of the `Add` method that we don't know about (or, worse, that you don't know about), simply summing up a filtered list of `Item` objects might not give you the results you're looking for.

You could still use Linq:

```
 foreach (Loan.Fee.Item currentFee in loan.Item.Fees.Where(x => x.Classification == 806)
 {
    class806.Add(currentFee);
 }
 return class806.Sum(x => x.Fee)
```

I'll confess that I'm a little perplexed by the class hierarchy implied here, though, in which the `Loan.Item.Fees` property is a collection of `Loan.Fee.Item` objects.  I don't know if what I'm seeing is a namespace hierarchy that conflicts with a class hierarchy, or if you're using nested classes, or what.  I know I don't like it.